# 'Need more than 1 value to unpack' error with a filter

Tags: django, django-errors

I have an error on a filter : `need more than 1 value to unpack`

Is it correct :

```
groups_list = Group.objects.filter({'assignment__in': editedcourse.assignment.all()})
```

I think it is a syntax error, or given arguments lack off but I can't correct it :/

Comment: try without { }

groups_list = Group.objects.filter('assignment__in': editedcourse.assignment.all())

Comment: I have another error : `invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without { } and  ''

```
groups_list = Group.objects.filter(assignment__in= editedcourse.assignment.all())
```

or

```
ids = map(lambda x:x.id,editedcourse.assignment.all())
groups_list = Group.objects.filter(assignment__in=ids)
```

Comment: First one is good, i was trying to mix with tuples.. thanks !

Comment: [Guido van Rossum hates map](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), use  list comprehension instead

Comment: with comprehension list:
ids = [course.id for course in editedcourse.assignment.all()]
groups_list = Group.objects.filter(assignment__in=ids)